# Is Gluon density the same in all protons?

Tags: subatomic

I was reading about [Gluons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gluon) and there it says

> The number and momentum distribution of the gluons in the proton
>   (gluon density) have been measured by two experiments

Is this gluon density the same for any proton or can different protons have different number and momentum distribution of gluons?

Comment: All protons are alike. (Well, their spin states may differ, but that should not affect your answer.)

Comment: @CosmasZachos But a proton at high momentum will have a higher apparent gluon density (up to the point, possibly, of gluon _saturation_ and the formation of a color-glass condensate, according to certain models mainly used in heavy-ion collisions).

Comment: @probably_someone  Yes, the gluon density *profile* WP is considering  is a distribution function (pdf) controlling all protons in similar circumstances.

Comment: @CosmasZachos in the articles I read, it says the proton spin is 1/2 . In which case the proton has a different spin state?

Comment: All *free* protons are alike. Some properties (like form factors and therefore structure functions and PDFs) vary in nuclear contexts.

Comment: Could be spin up or down, on a given axis. As I indicated, don't worry about it. @dmckee , Of course. I understood the issue is H1 and ZEUS measurements, so I avoid needless complication.

Comment: Probably [linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/355853/parton-distribution-function-interpretation).